# Calculate pressure within a cylider sealed on one end and inverted in water to various depths

Tags: fluid-dynamics

If I were to take a cylinder that is sealed on one end, and in an environment of typical air, invert the cylinder with the sealed end up and immerse the open end of the cylinder down vertically into a vessel of typical water, what would the air pressure be within the cylinder (in inches of water column or PSI) as I continue to push the cylinder down deeper into the water? I am looking for a way to calculate the pressure within the cylinder as I continue to lower it further into the water.  We thought the pressure (measured in inches of water column) would be equal to the inches of depth that the open end of the cylinder is immersed in the water but this does not seem to be the case (based on measurements we have taken). We would like to understand why the pressure in the cylinder (measured in inches water column) is not equal to the depth (in inches) to which the open end of the cylinder has been immersed. Thank You.

Comment: As the air volume inside the cylinder is made to decrease, its pressure increases.  So its pressure is higher than atmospheric pressure.  Are you familiar with the ideal gas law?

Answer (score 1):

The pressure of the air inside the cylinder is equal to the pressure in the water at the same horizontal level as the level of the air/water interface inside the cylinder.
That pressure will be due to the depth of water and the atmosphere above the water.